# Not able to create Liferay Plugin Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, liferay

I am new to liferay and i am trying to create a new Liferay Plugin Project.

I did a right click on  package explorer and clicked on 'New Liferay Plugin Project'.

After that i entered the Project and Display name then i selected the Liferay MVC as my portlet framework and i clicked finish.

As soon i click on finish, it shows "Error creating Liferay Plugin Project: Please see eclipse error log for the details".

After this i changed ivy.jar.url in build.properties file from "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-    2.3.0.jar"

to "=C:\Rahul13615\liferay\plugins.ivy\ivy-2.3.0.jar".

I did and still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Well have you looked at the Eclipse error log? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: Seems like connetivity issue to me.Are you connected to internet and not behind any proxy?Which liferay version are you using?

Comment: Yes i am connected to internet. I am using liferay 6.2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exact answer to your question, but for Liferay 6.2 development I recommend using Apache Maven 3 as build tool.

Download Maven separately https://maven.apache.org/ and install.

Then at command line run command (https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-liferay-maven-plugins-from-the-command-lin)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/liferay-ce
```

and choose desired plugin through wizard.

After that import that project as an Maven project to Eclipse IDE.

As you mentioned that you are new to Liferay development I recommend offical Liferay documentation but instead of Liferay MVC I recommend Spring MVC Portlet due to bigger community and documentation. Resources related to Spring development in Liferay couldn't be found at official Liferay documentation so it's better to Google for blog articles etc. I develop at Liferay 6.2, Spring, Spring Webflow, Spring MVC, Thymeleaf, Maven stack and I have few articles related to problems which I came across at my blog http://lukasgrygar.com

Answer (score 1):

**Office Network not allowed(Blocking) to create new liferay workspace Project**

We are facing some issues while trying to create new workspace in Liferay, When we are in Office network it fails. It's not accepting to auto download eclipse liferay projects's plugins. These repository sites are giving errors on eclipse connection time out.

**Note:** when we are in Citrix VM or open networks it works perfectly. Browser able to reach, If you hit below mentioned URL in browser.. But Its failing to reach at Eclipse level. https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/liferay/com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace/1.5.0/com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace-1.5.0.pom

**Eclipse Version**:Eclipse neon
**Liferay Version**:7.1

Comment: If your office network is not allowing outside network connectivity by default then you need to add network proxy, then it will allow to connect to eclipse n/w.

Comment: i mentioned proxies at setting.xml and location of setting.xml:C:\Users\userID\.m2.                                                                  proxies:<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>165.225.104.32</host>
      <port>9400</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>